# Oauth2 for google API access seems to be dependent on the user-ID of the requesting Python task

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I'm re-writing a program that needs ability to send and receive emails. The old version runs standalone on desktop and uses SMTP and POP3 to send and receive on my behalf using a gmail account. It's fine but, recently, a lot of sent emails have ended up in junk folders. So, I would like a more reliable way of "sending on behalf of" a user (me). The new version is a web app instead of a desktop program, so the email activities are done at the server end and I'm attempting to use the Gmail API.

I've been stuck for some days with inability to get the API access token ("invalid token") when the process runs on the server. Here's what I did:

1. Use Google Cloud Platform console to create/download a credentials.json file
2. Use the "quickstart" python code to successfully test user-authorization, saving tokens as a file token.json and send a test message
3. Incorporate similar code into my program but run it as a test from the command line > success!
4. Copy the entire folder to my server and, with an SSH terminal, run it again as a test from the command line > Success (including use of the Refresh token)!
5. Run it as a web app (WSGI Python) and it fails.

Noticing that the owner of the task is not me when it runs as a web app, on the SSH terminal, I changed user to "www-data" and re-tried the test and hit the error (cred.valid == False) after

`creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes=SCOPES)`
With the result that the User Authentication Flow is triggered - which is where it grinds to a halt as it can't be used remotely (I believe).

I've made sure that all the files in the folder are equally accessible to both users (www-data and ben). Can anyone give me a clue what I have to do to make it work with the "www-data" user?

```
def get_credentials():

    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']

    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    logging("In get_credentials. Python version: " + sys.version )
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        logging("Using token.json")
        with open('token.json',"r",encoding="utf-8") as fi:
            s = fi.read()
            logging( s )
        logging( str(os.environ))
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes=SCOPES)
        logging("Creds " + str(creds))

        logging(str(creds.refresh_token) + " " + str( creds.expired) + " " + str( creds.valid))
        
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        logging("No valid credentials found")
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            logging("Going for a refresh")
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            logging("Going for live authentication flow!")
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
            logging("Saved token.json")

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)


    return service
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that your using InstalledAppFlow.  This will cause the consent screen to pop up on the machine that the code is running on and then store the refresh token and access token in token.json.

What you could do is run it once localy to ensure that token.json is created and then make sure when you upload it to the server that token.json is also uploaded.

Remember that unless your application is set to production your refresh tokens are only going to be good for seven days so you will need to reauthorize it locally once once a week.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I did run it locally to create the token.json and included that file when uploading to the server.  That's how it ran OK as a command-line test on the server.  I don't think that I can get the application approved as "production" so the seven days limit is going to be a problem. Is there a better approach?

Comment: There is not refresh tokens for applications in testing only last for seven days.  Then you will need to authorize it again.